# How to open a google sheets spreadsheet at a specific row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a column that contains the dates of the year. It is used as a planning. Using conditional formatting, the date of today is coloured green. It would be nice to always open the spreadsheet at this specific row, when the document is loaded. Is this possible using Google Apps Script or using another Google Sheets setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sheet.getRange(row,1).activate()
```